# <input> and <select> widths

Tags: html, css

I am trying to put an `input` text box under a `select`, where the `input` is used to add new items to the `select`. Naturally, I want them the same width. However, this doesn't seem to work (I don't want to set different widths, because the difference needed may vary across browsers and platforms):

```
select, input {
 min-width: 16em;
}
```

The text box is six pixels wider than the `select`.

[image]

A forum post at http://forums.mozillazine.org/viewtopic.php?f=25&t=1555685 recommended that forcing content-box sizing on both (rather than border-box or other defaults) would make them the same. This helped a bit, increasing the `select` width by two pixels, but the text box is still four pixels wider:

```
select, input {
 min-width: 16em;
 box-sizing: content-box;
 -moz-box-sizing: content-box;
}
```

[image]

A thing I thought to try out was have a container with the `16em` width and set its two children to `width: 100%;`, in the hope that they would be the same width. Unfortunately, that didn't work either:

[image]

Any other fixes I can try to make them the same width? I'm currently testing in Firefox 4.0b7 on Ubuntu 11.04 with the Darklooks GTK+ theme, though of course, I want a solution that works equally everywhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

on the wrap div you can add `display: -moz-groupbox;`

live example: http://jsbin.com/alixi5

Answer (score 2):

Do you have 1 pixel of left and right padding on the text input?

FireFox on a Mac they look the same width to me.
[image]

Comment: No, I don't. I understand that the code I've tried may work on other platforms/themes/browsers, but I want something that works on everything. Right now, as it doesn't work properly on my computer, that's not really everything.

Answer (score 1):

Put them inside a div with the width you want, and assign 100% width to both the select and input.

**Edit 1**
The following code works in my computer<sup>tm</sup>

```
<div style="width: 400px">
<select style="width:100%" multiple="multiple">
    <option>Value1</option>
    <option>Value2</option>
    <option>Value3</option>
    <option>Value4</option>
</select>
<input type="text" style="width:100%">
```

[image]
Works on Firefox 2.0, Chrome 8.0.552.215, IE8 8.0.7600.16385

Comment: Funnily enough I just tried that and was editing my question to include that as you were answering. Thanks for the help, but that doesn't work. The `input` is still wider than the `select`.

Comment: Did you assign zero margin to the input and select?

Comment: I have tried this and it has made no difference unfortunately.